# How do I take advantage of a specfic user's attributes to generate an encryption key pair on the fly to encrypt a file?

Tags: rsa

Suppose I have the following 3 files with content:

file1.txt:

```
This is file1.txt.  It is labeled red.
```

file2.txt:

```
This is file2.txt.  It is labeled green.
```

file3.txt:

```
This is file3.txt.  It is labeled blue.
```

Suppose these 3 files are stored on my linux file system at:

/home/shared

Finally, suppose I have 3 users who can login to this linux machine:

user1 (should only see files labeled red)
user2 (should only see files labeled green)
user3 (should only see files labeled blue)

How can I use the RSA encryption scheme to generate unique private keys for user1, user2, and user3 such that they can see the files they can decrypt the files they are supposed to see but not the ones they should not see?

Put another way, how can I generate a key pair (public/private) so that user1 can can encrypt red-labeled files and users 2 and 3 cannot decrypt file1.txt?

Comment: One solution may be to encrypt the file asymmetrically using the public key stored in the user's ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file.  Another solution might be to create a symmetric (AES) key 'on the fiy', encrypt the file using the AES key, then save the key to a file that is readable only by the user.

Comment: Are you asking how to build a public-key file encryption system from scratch, how to generate and use RSA keys for file encryption with `gpg` (or some other tool), or just how to put files in the home directory of user other than yourself? Or are you just trying to understand Unix file permissions?